# Center text in multiple bars into the same .progress

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

The code of the progress bar is :

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 35%">
    <span class="sr-only">35% Complete (success)</span>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" style="width: 20%">
    <span class="sr-only">20% Complete (warning)</span>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 10%">
    <span class="sr-only">10% Complete (danger)</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to write a text and put it in the center of those stacked progress bars .

The example is from bootstrap website and my code is similar except that I am using just 2 progress bars in the same one . But normally the solution should fit any case .

Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Without the css i can't reproduce your progress bar. You should try to add the property text-align:center; on your div's inside of the main div, for example:

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 35%;text-align:center;">
```

Try this and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Just Make each progress bar a div (like you already have) , then wrap the text inside that div and just make the text-align:center;

Comment: progress-bar already has text-align: center; applied to the class. If he wants text to be centered within each stacked bar (as opposed to the full 'progress' div then all he needs to do is remove class="sr-only"

Answer (score 0):

[View Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6kTjj/)

CSS

```
.progress-info { 
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-info">Hello, World!</div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 35%">
    <span class="sr-only">35% Complete (success)</span>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" style="width: 20%">
    <span class="sr-only">20% Complete (warning)</span>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 10%">
    <span class="sr-only">10% Complete (danger)</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I might have misunderstood. But I think you want the text to be centred within the entire progress bar, not each individual 'section' like the other suggestions?

Comment: Yes I would like to center it within the entire progress bar :-)